# Accelerate ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table storing members messages with 4 columns :

- message_id (primary key, auto incrementing)
- sender_id (key)
- receiver_id (key)
- message_content

I do lots of `SELECT`s and I always sort them by `message_id DESC`, with queries such as :

```
SELECT message_content 
FROM table 
WHERE sender_id='3333' 
ORDER BY message_id DESC 
LIMIT 30
```

in such queries, the `ORDER BY` is expensive (it typically has to sort through thousands of rows, which generates some load when multiplied by many requests each second)

Is there a way to avoid having to sort the table each time? Since I always want to retrieve results in the same order, and since the message_id column doesn't change over time, if each new table row was inserted in first position, the table would always be sorted and i wouldn't need any "ORDER BY" anymore.
Is that possible ? Or are there other solutions?

Thank you

Comment: FYI: Thousands of rows is generally child's play for a RDBMS. Indexing is almost always the answer to performance issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Specify `3333` as an integer, not a string (remove quotes)
2. Add `message_id` column to the `sender_id` index (if you use myisam, because in innodb it is added automatically by so called "[clustered index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-index-types.html)")

Comment: Thank you. Does specifying 3333 as an integer improve performance? Or is there an other reason for not having quotes?

Comment: message_id is already the primary key, so re-indexing it yet again may not help much.

Comment: @Marc B: if only he uses innodb. But indeed, totally forgot about it

Comment: @Eric: sometimes it could lead to "strange" behaviour

Comment: @Eric: so adding `message_id` to the `sender_id` index should help.

Comment: ok, but wouldn't the new index be as big as the original table? since all rows have different message_ids, the index would have as many "rows" as the table I guess

Comment: @Eric: mysql doesn't have compressed indexes feature (like say oracle has) so every index contains the amount comparable to the table (to be precise it equals to the table rows count - amount of null values)